# How to learn what processes have been eating CPU over a period of time?

Tags: cpu-load, diagnostic

I have a CPU that has been maxing at 100% for a few days. However, `htop` and `top` do not reveal any especially obvious processes consuming cycles.

How can I find out what is eating cycles?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the average of cpu usage and memory usage over a period of time in ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420569/how-to-calculate-the-average-of-cpu-usage-and-memory-usage-over-a-period-of-time)

Comment: @N0rbert No? the accepted answer makes mention of `cat /proc/loadavg` to report cumulative CPU usage, but I am looking for *breakdown* of cumulative CPU usage across processes. (It is *so* possible that I just do not understand the significance of the answer.)

Comment: I mean it mentions nice tool named `atop`.

Comment: `atop`, or internet search "Process Accounting". Also look at `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u cron`.